# Securing sqlite db in C# application

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I have a C# wpf application which uses sqlite db. I have the following function

```
public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
{
    string str = @"Data Source=mydb1.sqlite3";
    SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(str);
    con.SetPassword("mydbpass");
    con.Open();
    return con;
}
```

Previously I did not have this line con.SetPassword("mydbpass"); after I introduce it I get error SqliteException the file is encrpyted or is not a database ?
How can I protect my sqlite db ?

Comment: where does the file reside..? does it know the path to where the file is..?

Comment: Yes the file in the same directory with the .exe?